# Change database (em) with selector in Symfony 2 using multiple entity managers

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am wondering how to use two database connections (entity managers) in my application in symfony 2 and I have read how to work with multiple entity managers (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

In my case I would like to use two databases db2014 and db2015 that can allow to change with a select (combobox) and then change the default entity manager. With this configuration:

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            //connection for db2014
            default:
                driver:   "%database_driver%"
                host:     "%database_host%"
                port:     "%database_port%"
                dbname:   "%database_name%"
                user:     "%database_user%"
                password: "%database_password%"
                charset:  UTF8

            //connection for db2015
            db2015:
                driver:   "%database_driver2%"
                host:     "%database_host2%"
                port:     "%database_port2%"
                dbname:   "%database_name2%"
                user:     "%database_user2%"
                password: "%database_password2%"
                charset:  UTF8
```

I have understood this article but the main problem is that I must change the code controller to select the entity manager like this:

```
// All three return the "default/db2014" entity manager
$em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager();

// Both of these return the "db2015" entity manager
$db2015Em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager('db2015');
```

Can I set the default entity manager to don't change the controller code? or some ideas to how can i achieve it? I hope to explain well because my english is not very good.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I have the same problem. Did you find the answer to resolve the problem ?
thanks for answer

Comment: No! Sorry. I'm using symfony 2.3 and It seems that it is possible in 2.7 version.

Comment: I have got one more question. Could you tell me name of this feature in Symfony 2.7 or way to find it if you know it? Thanks you a lot.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the section for Doctrine ORM in your `config.yml` as well, as is described in the [Symfony Cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html)

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        [...]
    orm:
        default_entity_manager: db2015
        entity_managers:
            db2015:
                connection: db2015
                mappings:
                    AcmeDemoBundle:  ~
                    AcmeStoreBundle: ~
            db2014:
                connection: db2014
                mappings:
                    AcmeCustomerBundle: ~
```

Comment: Thanks, yes I know my config.yml was incomplete, but mainly my question is if I could set the em as default I didn't need to change my code in the controller using always this: $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getManager(); Do you understand which is my point?